# Sentence structure - "The same.. as"

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's a sentence that I'd like to ask about.

> 1. When you're in emotional pain, treat yourself with the same compassion you would expect from a truly good friend.

Here, can I insert 'as' to make a thorough sentence - "the same ~ as" ?

> 2. When you're in emotional pain, treat yourself with the same compassion **as** you would expect from a truly good friend.

Or, is there any difference between #1 and #2?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's grammatically correct to use "as" in the statement presented above.  You use "the same" followed by "as" in the pattern "the same + as + noun/pronoun. For example,I have got the same problem as you. He is the same age as Adam.

On the other hand, you use that/who/which, depending on the context, in the following pattern:  The same +noun + that/which/who +clause.  For example, it's the same film (that) I saw last year.  So you have to use "that", not as, before the last clause as follows:

When you are in emotional pain, treat yourself with the same compassion (that) you would expect from a truly good friend.